# Best way to pass URL parameters to a Salesforce Community Lightning Component

Tags: community

I am looking for the best approach to pass parameters from a Communities URL (e.g. https://CommunitiesDomain/s/"My Custom Page"?customvar1=var1&customvar2=var2)

The URL parameters would populate the page with the variables

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [URL Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

```
var parsedUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
console.log(parsedUrl.searchParams.get("Your Parameter"))
//Do Something With Your Parameters
```

This is pretty straightforward, supported by all modern browsers (needles to say IE  support is dubious)

Answer (score 1):

This is still an idea see [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TrLwQAK) you can parse URL parameters to get the values 
Controller.js

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event) {

        var action = component.get("c.findApps");
        action.setCallback(this, function(a) {



            // the function that reads the url parameters
            var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
                var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
                    sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
                    sParameterName,
                    i;

                for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
                    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

                    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
                        return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
                    }
                }
            };

            //set the src param value to my src attribute
            component.set("v.src", getUrlParameter('src'));



            var settings = a.getReturnValue();            
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);       
    }
})
```

Component.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="CustomAppLauncherController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" >

    <aura:attribute name="src" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    {!v.src}

</aura:component>
```

Referenced from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000g1blIAA)

Answer (score 0):

The Lightning "Digital Experience" allows query parameters to be mapped into parameters for page-level components simply by using the "{!parameterName}" expression value. This is substituted by taking the equivalent query parameter's value and passing it to the component as an API property.

For example, a URL like `.../my-page?someParam=123` allows the value 123 to be passed to a component when that component has an API property to receive it and where you set that property's value to `{!someParam}` in the page editor's component property dialog.